# VHDL process rising edge

Tags: vhdl

Im trying to implement a system to create several clock I need for other systems, but my process is not working properly.

It seems like it doesnt find the risign edge of the clock, as the couters maintain on 0

The mclk signal is created by a clocking wizard IP.

This is the code I have :

```
entity clk_generator is
   port(
   
    clk : in std_logic;     --(100 MHz)
    
    
    mclk_o : out std_logic;  --(22.579 MHz)
    bclk : out std_logic;   --MCLK/8
    lrclk : out std_logic  --SCLK/64
    
    );
    
end clk_generator;



architecture Behavioral of clk_generator is

component clk_wiz_0
  port ( 
    mclk : out std_logic;
    clk_in1 : in std_logic;
    reset : in std_logic := '0'
  );
    end component;
   signal mclk_i : std_logic;
   signal bclk_couter: integer :=0;
   signal lrclk_couter : integer :=0; 
   
begin

clk_gen : clk_wiz_0

port map(
    
    clk_in1 => clk,
    mclk => mclk_i   
    
   
    );
mclk_o <= mclk_i;

    process(clk) is
    
    begin
    
    if rising_edge(mclk_i) then
        bclk_couter <= bclk_couter +1;
        
        if bclk_couter = 4 then
            bclk <= '1';
        end if;
        
        if bclk_couter = 8 then
            bclk <= '0';
            lrclk_couter  <= lrclk_couter + 1;
            bclk_couter <= 0;
        end if;
        
        if lrclk_couter = 32 then
            lrclk <= '1';
        end if;
        
        if lrclk_couter = 64 then
            lrclk <= '0';
            lrclk_couter <= 0;
        end if;
    end if;
    end process;

end Behavioral;
```

[image: simulation]

My process is not working as I supposed, apparently the rising edge is not being detected

Answer (score 2):

The sensitivity list on the process should be the things that cause the simulation to rerun the process.

So, use the right clock in the process sensitivity list.

```
process(mclk_i) is
begin
if rising_edge(mclk_i) then
```

If your simulation tool allows VHDL-2008, then use `process(all)` to never see this problem ever again. [reference.](https://docs.xilinx.com/r/en-US/ug901-vivado-synthesis/Using-the-process-all-Statement)

Comment: I changed the sensitivity list but keep getting the same result :( , I will try to find a solution on other way.

Comment: Ok so now the couters are working properly, but they are starting from a really high negative value, but I instantiated them to 0.  Any clues??

Comment: @AlvaroSuarezMenendez: Which simulator are you using, and could you include another screenshot of the waveform?

Comment: @AlvaroSuarezMenendez Since the initialization error is another issue, please search this site for similar and answered questions, as you are supposed to do. I'm sure this issue is answered multiple times already. -- If you are sure you cannot find anything similar, feel free to post a new question for this. Make sure to include the current source, as it needs to be self-contained. You might link back here, if you desire.